# Bootstrap: Stop last columns under the second last column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have three different height of the columns (lg-box, md-box and sm-box).I want to show the column #7 in the next line but not sure why it is filling the empty space and coming up under the column 6. It should show in the next line. It works fine when I have less than 7 or more than 8 columns but it creates a problem only when I have total 7 columns. Is possible to stop filling the empty space of column 6?

[image]

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awaises/wumnLz96/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-2 lg-box">1</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 lg-box">2</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 lg-box">3</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 lg-box">4</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 lg-box">5</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 md-box">6</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 sm-box">7</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col-xs-2{
    border:2px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.lg-box{
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
}
.md-box{
    background-color: red;
    height: 120px;
}
.sm-box{
    background-color: green;
    height: 60px
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: If you are concerned for support for older browsers in relation to this answer, please consider using a flexbox polyfill, like https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility

You also can use bootstrap's row class to declare new rows.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 lg-box">1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 lg-box">2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 lg-box">3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 lg-box">4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 lg-box">5</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 md-box">6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-2 sm-box">7</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wumnLz96/1/

If you want to keep the dynamic number of columns, use a flex container to wrap them.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 lg-box">1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 lg-box">2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 lg-box">3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 lg-box">4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 lg-box">5</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 md-box">6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 sm-box">7</div>
</div>

.col-xs-2{
    border:2px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.lg-box{
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
}
.md-box{
    background-color: red;
    height: 120px;
}
.sm-box{
    background-color: green;
    height: 60px
}
.row{ 
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wumnLz96/2/

Comment: Oh, I cannot use extra row for the last columns because all columns are generating based on program logic. Sometimes columns are less and sometimes more.

Comment: Do you have control over the element that contains those columns?

Comment: Yes, the Second solution is the Great. The columns are dynamic and your solution works fine even I have less or more columns. Really appreciate.

Comment: @AwaisImran But beware, flex has limited IE support and a few other bugs in other browsers:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Yes, always important to consider.

Answer (score 0):

use `clear` to stop floating elements on left.

```
<div class="col-xs-2 sm-box" style="clear: left;">7</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add clearfix before your last column like this:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
<div class="col-xs-2 sm-box">7</div>
```

This will be clear and allow you to control clearfix visibility and so the number of columns for different media sizes.

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/33048/) for example.